# hook_tokens_alter() not applying to [user:one-time-login-url] Token

Tags: 7, users, tokens

I'm trying to alter the one time login token. I am implementing hook_tokens_alter to do this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens_alter
 * @param $replacements
 * @param $context
 */
function portalapi_tokens_alter(&$replacements,  $context){
  if(isset($context['data']['user'])){
    foreach($context['tokens'] as $name => $original){
      switch ($name) {
        case 'one-time-login-url':
          $timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
          $token = user_pass_rehash($context['data']['user']->pass, $timestamp, $context['data']['user']->login, $context['data']['user']->uid);
          $resetpath = url(variable_get('portal_frontend_url').'/reset-password/'.$token.'-'.$timestamp);
          $replacements[$original] = $resetpath;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Logging the $replacements array at the end of the function call shows the expected changes. However, the token output isn't altered when used (for example when sending password reset emails).

As a quick background here - We're implementing an entirely headless front end serviced by an API, we need to use a different domain in the one time login link and a different structure.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot alter it because that token is not returned from [`user_tokens()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.tokens.inc/function/user_tokens/7.x). You get that token only with code similar to the following one.

```
$text_with_tokens_replaced = token_replace($text, $variables, array('language' => $language, 'callback' => 'user_mail_tokens', 'sanitize' => FALSE, 'clear' => TRUE));
```

The problem is that first the implementations of `hook_tokens_alter()` are called, then the callback passed to `token_replace()` is called. The effect is that every value you set for that token is then changed from the callback.

This is the code used from [`token_replace()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x).

```
  $replacements = array();
  foreach ($text_tokens as $type => $tokens) {
    $replacements += token_generate($type, $tokens, $data, $options);
    if (!empty($options['clear'])) {
      $replacements += array_fill_keys($tokens, '');
    }
  }

  // Optionally alter the list of replacement values.
  if (!empty($options['callback']) && function_exists($options['callback'])) {
    $function = $options['callback'];
    $function($replacements, $data, $options);
  }
```

[`token_generate()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_generate/7.x) is the function invoking the token hooks (including the alter hooks).

```
  $replacements = module_invoke_all('tokens', $type, $tokens, $data, $options);

  // Allow other modules to alter the replacements.
  $context = array(
    'type' => $type,
    'tokens' => $tokens,
    'data' => $data,
    'options' => $options,
  );
  drupal_alter('tokens', $replacements, $context);
```

Comment: Well thats frustrating.

Thanks for confirming the issue, i'll have to generate a custom token and make sure i catch all of the places the one time login token is used then.

Comment: Drupal allows you to change the message sent via email when a user registers, forgets the password, etc. It would be easy to edit the message to use your own token.

Comment: Just got bitten by this one. Would be nice if `hook_token_alter` could apply to all tokens, however seems that's not the case. Will define a custom token instead.